# Converting a 1st order non-linear recurrence to a 2nd order

Tags: algorithms, recurrence-relations

I came across this problem while reading [Blelloch's Prefix Sums
and Their Applications](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~guyb/papers/Ble93.pdf):

Show how the recurrence $x_i = a_i + b_i/x_{i-1}$

where + is numeric addition and / is division, can be converted into a $2^{nd}$ degree recurrence of the form:

$\begin{equation}
  x_i=\begin{cases}
    a_i, & \text{$0 \leq i\lt2$}\\
    (x_{i-1} \otimes a_{i,1} )\oplus(x_{i-2} \otimes a_{i,2})\oplus b_i, & \text{$2 \leq i \lt n$}.
  \end{cases}
\end{equation}
$

Where $ \oplus$ is *associative*, $ \otimes$ is *semi-associative* and  $ \otimes$ *distributes over* $ \oplus$.

One this form is achieved, one can employ (parallel) prefix sum to compute $x_i$.

**Initial findings**:

1) Since division is neither associative nor does it distribute over addition, some sort of a clever transform is called for.

2) I thought about using transform $y_i := \log(x_i)$. While this will conveniently handle the division, it creates another problem, i.e. $\log()$ of a sum. Besides, it would have been $1^{st}$ not $2^{nd}$ order which the problem specifies.

Could you offer me some hints please?

Comment: Denote $\otimes$ the inverse operator. It is **semi** associative meaning there exists another operator $\times$ (which here is the usual multiplication) such that $(a \otimes b) \otimes c = a \otimes (b \times c)$.

Comment: Thanks for the input. Are you suggesting that the division (/) be the $\otimes$? If that is the case, I still have a problem: Divison does not distribute over $\oplus$ which is ordinary addition (+) in this case.